# What's the difference between JCreator 4.5 and JCreator 5?

Tags: java, ide, jcreator

My school uses 4.5 and there doesn't seem to be any differences besides the version number

Comment: Look at the history http://www.jcreator.com/history.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the article at their web site http://www.jcreator.com/forums/index.php?showtopic=7803 , it contains release notes for version 5.0.  Sounds like the debugger has improved.

Regarding Eclipse, i agree that it is simply a better IDE than most.  I have not used JCreator too much, but have used a little, along with BlueJ and notepad ++.  Eclipse can be a little overwhelming at first, but its intelligence is impressive. Eclipse is particularly well suited for Java. Here a couple other posts about Eclipse on this site.

[Best Eclipse version for Java development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305708/best-eclipse-version-for-java-development)

[Is Eclipse the best IDE for Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152691/is-eclipse-the-best-ide-for-java)

Answer (score 0):

It's (5.0) is faster and utilizes memory better.

Answer (score -1):

A bit off topic but to be honest, Eclipse is simply the best Java IDE out there. JCreator isn't terribad but Eclipse blows it out of the water.

Comment: We're using JCreator for simplicity 'cause it doesn't create extra files like workspace and source and bin folders and which would easily confuse the non computer oriented kids when they go email their assignments to the teacher. I could use Eclipse if I wanted to but our school's computers are reeeeally slow